# DB2, MERGE INTO update if value different

Tags: sql, db2

I have this kind of DB2 request which work

```
MERGE INTO table_to_upsert AS tab
USING (VALUES
        (1, 2, 3),
        (4, 5, 6),
        (7, 8, 9)
        -- more rows
    ) AS merge (C1, C2, C3)
    ON tab.key_to_match = merge.key_to_match -- usually the primary key example : tab.C2 = merge.C2
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET tab.C1 = merge.C1,
                   tab.C2 = merge.C2,
                   tab.C3 = merge.C3
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (C1, C2, C3)
        VALUES (merge.C1, merge.C2, merge.C3)
```

But now, what I want is, IF primary key already existe, then update, BUT only update C1 if the new value of C1 is different from the old one.

In theory something like that

```
MERGE INTO table_to_upsert AS tab
USING (VALUES
        (1, 2, 3),
        (4, 5, 6),
        (7, 8, 9)
        -- more rows
    ) AS merge (C1, C2, C3)
    ON tab.key_to_match = merge.key_to_match
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET tab.C1 = merge.C1,
                   tab.C2 = merge.C2,
                   tab.C3 = merge.C3
        WHERE tab.C1 != merge.C1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (C1, C2, C3)
        VALUES (merge.C1, merge.C2, merge.C3)
```

I add the `WHERE tab.C1 != merge.C1` but it's not working, result in

> Error: ILLEGAL SYMBOL WHERE; VALID SYMBOLS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can add one search condition to the matched line, i.e.

```
MERGE INTO table_to_upsert AS tab
USING (VALUES
        (1, 2, 3),
        (4, 5, 6),
        (7, 8, 9)
        -- more rows
    ) AS merge (C1, C2, C3)
    ON tab.key_to_match = merge.key_to_match
    WHEN MATCHED AND tab.C1 != merge.C1 THEN
        UPDATE SET tab.C1 = merge.C1,
                   tab.C2 = merge.C2,
                   tab.C3 = merge.C3
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (C1, C2, C3)
        VALUES (merge.C1, merge.C2, merge.C3)
```